# Player Climb Code in C# error

Tags: c#

I am having some trouble with a piece of code that I am working on in C#.

What this code is meant to do is move the player up and forward so that he is standing on a 1x1x1 block in front of him and not allow him to get over anything that is 1x2x1 or higher. but I am having a problem , [Image](http://postimg.org/image/x361nwlah/). The further away I get from 0,0,0 the worse it gets. could anyone help me?

Code:

```
         //Player Climbs Up One Block Heights But Dose Not Climb Anything Higher
    if ((PlayerClimAction.posOneHit == true) && (PlayerClimAction.posTwoHit == false))
        {


        // Moves the Player Up By 0.9
        controller.Move ((transform.position + transform.up * (float) 0.9f) * Time.deltaTime); 

        // Moves The Player Forward By 0.9
        controller.Move ((transform.TransformDirection (input) * (float) 0.9f) * Time.deltaTime); 

        //Debug
        print("Up Vector3: " + (transform.position + transform.up * (float) 0.9f) * Time.deltaTime); 

        print("////////////////////////////////////////////////");

        print ("Forward: " + (transform.TransformDirection (input) * (float) 0.9f) * Time.deltaTime);

        // Reset Triggers
        PlayerClimAction.posOneHit = false;
        PlayerClimAction.posTwoHit = false;


    }else
    {
        controller.Move (motion * Time.deltaTime); // Move Normaly
    }
```

Comment: Ok so this might help out a bit. [Image](http://postimg.org/image/bn7j5uhbx/) : this is a visual of what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big thanks to Tone for the information. Thanks to that I was able to edit my code and change it to this:

```
     //Player Climbs Up One Block Heights But Dose Not Climb Anything Higher
    if ((PlayerClimAction.posOneHit == true) && (PlayerClimAction.posTwoHit == false))
        {

        // Moves the Player Up By 0.5
        controller.Move ((transform.up * (float) 0.5f)); 

        // Moves The Player Forward
        controller.Move (motion * Time.deltaTime); // Move Normaly


        // Reset Triggers
        PlayerClimAction.posOneHit = false;
        PlayerClimAction.posTwoHit = false;

    }else
    {
        controller.Move (motion * Time.deltaTime); // Move Normaly
    }
```

I changes the forward movement in the climb to just be a duplicate of the regular movement in the `else` statement, because that is the distance and speed that the player would move normally, and because of Tone's suggestion that I should change `controller.Move ((transform.position + transform.up * (float) 0.9f) * Time.deltaTime);` to `controller.Move (transform.up * (float) 0.9f * Time.deltaTime);` really helped me out in smoothing things out.

TY to all who looked at the post.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that the argument to `controller.Move` is a movement vector rather than an absolute position (that's what the rest of your code suggests)

The line

```
controller.Move ((transform.position + transform.up * (float) 0.9f) * Time.deltaTime);
```

should read

```
controller.Move (transform.up * (float) 0.9f * Time.deltaTime);
```

If on the other hand the argument to controller.Move should be an absolute position you have several issues

a) the first call to `controller.Move` multiplies `transform.position` by `Time.deltaTime`. This will result in movement on all axes (and is why it gets worse the further away from 0,0,0)

b) the second and third calls to `controller.Move` don't include `transform.Position` in the calculation (depending on what `transform.TransformDirection` and `mostion` represent). Also I assume that is a typo and should be `motion`.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help so far :D `private CharacterController controller;` and                                                                                    `controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();` that is the code for controller. I am using the `charatorController` variable type. tell me if that helps. I tried the changes and all that it did was ping the player off in the same off target direction as before but now to an extreme value. ty for the suggestion

Comment: and `TransformDirection (input)` is refuting to the direction the player is facing which is based on the key input , WASD or Up Down Left Right,

Comment: I have also fixed the typo XD. you got to love them

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted.